# formatting slack messages using curl with slack api similar to IFTTT app

Tags: curl, slack-api, slack

I've been trying to get my messages into slack channels via CURL and also to have the same formatting as the messages that are sent by IFTTT. I am able to get the messages to post, but I am unable to get the thumbnail to appear on the right side of the message like it does when IFTTT sends. Since I don't have enough reputation to attach images to this post, It's going to be really hard to explain this. I have been trying everything I can and I cannot get this figured out.

This is what I have tried based on what I am able to locate when inspecting the code that IFTTT sends to slack.

`curl -X POST --data-urlencode 'payload={"channel":"#testapi","username":"IFTTT","icons":    {"image_48":"https://slack.global.ssl.fastly.net/20653/img/services/ifttt_48.png"},"attachments":[{"title":"Cloudy today!","title_link":"http://www.weather.com/weather/5-day/USOH0251","thumb_url":"http://ifttt.com/images/weather/cloudy.png","thumb_width":310,"thumb_height":310,"text":"Cloudy today! With a high of 34F and a low of 25F.","fallback":"Cloudy today! With a high of 34F and a low of 25F.","mrkdwn_in":["text","pretext"]}],"mrkdwn":true,"type":"message","subtype":"bot_message","ts":"1415874505.000002"}' https://hooks.slack.com/services/0000000/00000000/00000000`

When I try the same everything posts, but the thumbnail image off to the right side does not appear.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: I was told by the SlackAPI twitter account that this is currently a private API that's used for their internal integrations.  However, they're working on a public version "soon" take that as you will, my fingers are crossed!